# SP.ScriptHelpers object

Tags: 2013, javascript

Just noticed the object the other day, and it looks like its on every page. But I can't find any documentation about it. Anyone used the "helpers" or seen any docs, or knows anything about it?

Tbh I'm not a fan about using undocumented features too much, since I guess they could change the functions.

Here are some of the functions:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice catch! I did a little bit of digging and found out that the function is defined in the `sp.init.js` file. You can see the debug version here: `_layouts/15/sp.init.debug.js`

Yes this function is undocumented like many of other SP JS features. But I am not too worried about MS changing these functions as they are used in functionality like the SharePoint Newsfeed. (Go to any page with the newsfeed and search for the `SP.ScriptHelper` object)

To add to the answer, there is another Helper object: [SP.ScriptUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff409735%28v=office.14%29.aspx) which I have used successfully in SP2010 as well as SP2013

Comment: Many methods are duplicated across ScriptUtility and ScriptHelper. Not sure why, but usually its fine to just use ScriptHelper it seems.